# knowing the bundle id of another app, may enable to hack the keychain access?

Tags: ios, swift, app-id, bundle-identifier

I was really thinking is it possible that if a hacker gets bundle id of my app, the hacker can get access to key-chain of the my app ?
asak, bundle id are unique and hence it cannot be re-used.

I'm not sharing the keychain. If hacker somehow knows the bundle ID of my app, will hacker be able to access my app's keychain ?

thanks

Comment: @Hardik Thakkar,@BIBIN K ONANKUNJU,@Polygnome,@Attersson - easily you guys put it on hold, instead of helping to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

No. You have to allow it specifically for which apps are you sharing the keychain.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps

Comment: I'm not sharing the keychain. If hacker somehow knows the bundle ID of my app, will hacker be able to access my app's keychain ?

Comment: No. As I said. Without you explicitly saying you want to share it, he won't get the values

Comment: Even if you were sharing the keychain, the hacker would need an app that was associated with your development team

Comment: @Paulw11 - assuming condition which you mentioned above, den is it possible ?

Comment: To do that the hacker has to have your Apple ID login to the Apple's developer program and sign an app and get it installed on the device. If they physically have the device and the passcode then they can get the keychain without knowing your bundle id. If they don't physically have the device and the passcode then there is nothing they can do